# Cannot implement a constructor (Implicit super constructor Item() is undefined)

Tags: java, constructor, superclass

I'm trying to implement the constructor of a class that has more parameters than the parent class, the only one in common is the title. When I try to implement the constructor in the Book class, it shows me an error "Implicit super constructor Item() is undefined".

```
public class Book extends Item {

private String author = "";
private String ISBN = "";
private String publisher = "";

public Book(String theTitle, String theAuthor, String theIsbn, String thePublisher){

}
```

}

Parent class constructor;

```
public abstract class Item {

private String title;
private int playingTime;
protected boolean gotIt;
private String comment;

public Item(String title, int playingTime, boolean gotIt, String comment) {
    super();
    this.title = title;
    this.playingTime = playingTime;
    this.gotIt = gotIt;
    this.comment = comment;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your super class doesn't have an no-args default constructor, so you have to explicitly invoke the super class's overloaded constructor using super() keyword passing the default values.

```
public Book(String theTitle, String theAuthor, String theIsbn, String thePublisher){
super(thTitle,0,false,null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have not defined no-argument constructor, or provide parameters in super(....)

Answer (score 0):

java doesn't added no-argument constructor if you are adding constructor with one or more parameter. Java adds no-argument constructor if we don't add any constructor in class.
Other way around for your problem is you need to overload the constructor like

```
public Item(String title, int playingTime, boolean gotIt, String comment) {
    super(); //remove this constructor or define no-arg constructor in super class.
    super(thTitle,0,false,null); //add this constructor
}
```

## YouNeedToReadHeadFirstCoreJava